# How to have high agitation caused by high air flow while heating the same air?

Tags: thermodynamics, air, convection, fan

It may not be possible but I am trying to create an environment that has decent air flow for agitation. I want that environment to receive heat though through convection so increasing temperature over time. What is the best way to achieve this?  I basically have a fan in ducting with a heater past it. Is there anything I can do geometrically to achieve this?  A cone would increase pressure but not sure of the effects to the heat transfer.

I want maximum agitation with optimal increase in temperature.  Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You make the outlet as nozzle. With smaller flow area, the nozzle exit velocity increases which introduces more turbulence for agitation and high velocity is good for convection heat transfer as well if the jet pass the object to be heated.